# Should we have an "apologetics-study" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have but one [apologetics](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apologetics) tag.  This tag is currently [being reviewed to clarify its use and intent](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6586/how-to-improve-the-apologetics-tag-wiki).  The purpose of this qustion (which is related), is to ascertain whether we need a second tag (which kinda depends on what we do with the linked meta discussion).

**Proposal:** Should we create an [apologetics-study](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apologetics-study)tag, which would be a tag for questions *about apologetics,* meaning they are questions about what Apologetics is, how apologetic arguments are developed, what makes a good apologist.  In other words, the tag would refer to the study, field, or process of Apologetics.

Contrast this with the existing [apologetics](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apologetics) tag, which would be a tag identifying a question as needing assistance developing a *specific* apologist argument.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really think two tags are needed, but if the site community thinks two are warranted then I think it should be the other way round - [apologetics](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apologetics) should be about the field as a whole, and a new tag, perhaps [apologetic-arguments](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apologetic-arguments) should be about particular apologetic arguments, whether ones the OP knows about, or questions asking for help developing them.